# How do i use the closurebuilder for compiling and minifying scripts

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I am totally new to closure-library and am getting started. I just installed Python on my windows7 machine want to concatenate and minify the scripts. I ran through some commands as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder) but no gain. here are some parameters

- Python installed in `c:\python27\python.exe`
- Closure library in `c:\closure\`
- Closure compiler in `c:\closure\bin\build\compiler.jar`
- My Javascript file in `D:\projects\closureapp\js\index.js`

contents of the index.js is as below

```
/// <reference path="../closure/base.js" />
/// <reference path="../closure/dom/dom.js" />


/*Hello world into Closure Library Example*/

//Load the dom module
goog.require("goog.dom");


//refer the document body
var pageBody = document.body;

//after the body is loaded execute and add a header
pageBody.onload = function () {

    //create a header for the page
    var pageHeader = goog.dom.createDom('h1', { 'style': 'background-color:#EEE' }, 'Hello world!');

    //append the header to the document body
    goog.dom.appendChild(pageBody, pageHeader);

};
```

I executed the command below to produce compiled javascript but no gains

```
c:\python27\python.exe c:\closure\bin\build\c
losurebuilder.py --root=closure/ --root=d:\Projects\closureapp\js\ --
output_mode=compiled  --compiler_jar=compiler.jar > d:\Projects\closureapp\js\output.js
```

i get some weird messages like below

```
c:\closure\bin\build\closurebuilder.py: Building dependency tree..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\closure\bin\build\closurebuilder.py", line 257, in <module> main()
  File "c:\closure\bin\build\closurebuilder.py", line 204, in main tree = depstree.DepsTree(sources)
  File "c:\closure\bin\build\depstree.py", line 56, in __init__ raise NamespaceNotFoundError(require, source)
  depstree.NamespaceNotFoundError: Namespace "goog.async.Deferred" never provided.
  Required in Source closure\messaging\portchannel.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the same issue as http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/issues/detail?id=316

Comment: --root=third_party as per John

Comment: Does this mean the closure compiler is dead? A big identified 4 years ago that would basically make the documented example not work: https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder I liked the idea of closure compiler but seems to have gone from hard to use to almost impossible to use.

Comment: Not at all.  You only need to look at the github project to know that it is still under active development.  In what way has it gotten harder to use?  As far as I know the python script see little use, however.  At least I never use them.

Comment: @John you never use them? How do you calculate the dependencies? Can the compiler do it now?